# docker windows express typescript hot-reload

Tags: typescript, windows, express, nodemon

I'm trying to create a scaffold for my application, which basically is dockerized with node express & graphql within it.

the hot-reload runs on local (without docker) but fails on dockerized version.

Here's my code.

**TSCONFIG**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "rootDir":"./src",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true
  },
  // "include": ["src/**/*"],
  // "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

**package.json**

```
<redacted>
"scripts":{
"start": "ts-node ./src/server.ts",
}
<redacted>
```

**nodemon.json**

```
{
    "ignore": ["**/*.test.ts", "**/*.spec.ts", "node_modules"],
    "watch": ["src"],
    "exec": "npm start",
    "ext": "ts"
  }
```

**dockerfile**

```
FROM node:18

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY nodemon.json ./

COPY tsconfig*.json ./

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install -g ts-node

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npx", "nodemon"]
```

as usual I build it using docker commands.

```
docker build -t "scaffold:latest" .
docker run -p 3000:3000 -d -v "%cd%":/usr/src/app scaffold
```

I've seen some threads saying that I need to use legacy-watch when using docker-nodemon-windows stack and I do not know how to implement it when using nodemon.json

I tried installing ts-node globally but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a little confusion on what docker does:

1. provides a virtualized environment where running an application
2. provides an entry point, an application that needs to run when the image is put into execution ( container )
3. when that application stop or restarts the container dies

I think is good practice not to use a development tool like nodemon in a docker container, I am not sure what are you trying to achieve?